# javascript callback - execution of scripts is in random order

Tags: javascript, callback

I have this problem - while executing this function

```js
function(){
    var after = function(){                       
        server.executescript("scriptname")
    };
    var before = function (callback) {
        server.executescript("scriptname2")
        callback();
    };
    before(after);
}
```

execution of scripts is in random order and not as I would expect:

1. scriptname2
2. scriptname

what am I missing?

Thank you!

Comment: Read about Sync and Async functions.

Comment: where did you declare `server`?

Comment: just a pseudo code meaning that we are executing some script on server

Comment: Basically you don't know in advance which script will arrive first over the network. If they need to be in a specific order, you need to wait for the previous to arrive before loading the next one. Or switch to a system where you can load them all first, but then activate them in order instead of activating them upon loading.

Comment: @AnkitKumar - shouldn't callback resolve this?

Comment: @radovan, No. Just read about Async functions, that will help you.

Comment: No, callbacks don't solve this since you immediately call the callback. You would need something like `server.executescript("scriptname2").onload = callback;`, that will only call the cllback once the currently loading script has executed.

Comment: @Shilly - thanks! "you need to wait for the previous to arrive" - any idea how to check this?

Comment: script onload event handler, fetch request onload handler, Promises, so many options. Read about Sync and Async and pick whatever solution fits your code best.

Comment: thanks! I appreciate!

Answer (score 0):

this seems to work

```
function(){
    function after(){
        server.executescript("scriptname");
    }
    function before(){
        return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
            server.executescript("scriptname2");
            resolve();
        });
    }
    before().then(after);
}
```

thank you all for participating!

Answer (score -1):

The order you are seeing is the one expected:

```js
var after = async function() {
  await console.log("scriptname");
};

var before = async function (callback) {
  await console.log("scriptname2");
  callback();
};

before(after);
```

1. You first call the "before()" function which is going to call your "scriptname2".
2. Then you will call your "callback()" which is your "after()" function.
3. Which is going to call your "scriptname".

Comment: I am seeing random order, not that one (which I expected)

Comment: Can you share the code of your function `server.executescript`? They must be the ones messing up with the order.

Comment: @radovan you can try the updated solution with async/await, maybe that would solve your issue.

Comment: Sorry, nope. Thanks for trying however

Comment: Vote down was not necessary though, I was just trying to help :(

Comment: I totally agree with you Armel. It was not mine.